# Find keys in JSON with regex and put them in map in java

Tags: java, json, dictionary, key, key-value

I have JSON from a API similar to this:

```
{
  "something": "something",
  "example_1": true,
  "something2": "something",
  "example_2": false,
  "example_3": true
}
```

I want to put all the example_x keys with their values in a map. Im guessing that's possible with regex but I don't know how to do it.

I do know that  `example_\d` would be the regex but that's it. I didn't find any similar questions but I maybe used the wrong search terms.

Info: I use the org.json Library for getting the JSON Object but I can change that to another Library if it works.

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: Please show the code you have so far.

Comment: As i said i have no idea how to solve the problem properly and because of that no code. I would know how to make it but I think it's really unoptimised: a for loop that checks with jsonobject.has() if it contains example_i and if yes adds the key and value to a map until it can't find the next one

Comment: You've parsed the JSON into a JSONObject? Then iterate over the fields checking whether the names match your pattern.

Comment: Okay i will look that up, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with this: (Thanks to tgdavies for telling me to use a Iterator)

```
//jsonObject is the json in the question for example
HashMap Map<String, Boolean> = new HashMap<>();

Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
while (keys.hasNext()) {
    String key = keys.next();
    if (key.matches("example_\\d+")) {
        Map.put(key, jsonObject.getBoolean(key));
    }
}
```